# How to prevent users from spoofing a license server?

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have windows program and I want to make my own license server. I don't like to generate any key manually. The idea is to check on server two copies running at the same time.

My algorithm.

> 1. User buy license key.
> 2. Server script insert key into server database.
> 3. User enters  key into the program. The program insert it into its database.
> 4. User start program. After that, program login to the server using the license key. And logout when user close program.
> 5. If there are two copies login to server same time using the same key, server script deactivates license key.

But how would I prevent a malicious user from spoofing the license server if they added a fake server to the HOSTS file in Windows?

Maybe my server should return something unique in answer after program authentication and the program would use that information to determine whether the license server is legitimate instead of a fake server. But what kind of information would it need to return for this purpose?

Comment: Your question is what?  How to modify a HOSTS file programmatically?  That may not be possible in a practical way; viruses also write to the host file, so Windows now guards that file very closely.

Comment: how to avoid fake server in hosts file if I want to check online license key?

Comment: what unique answer must return license server that programm could understand that it connects to license server but not fake server?  May be someone have his own ideas about this problem

Comment: Why would you need a fake server?

Comment: @Robert, Alex wants to prevent his program from talking to a "fake" server that fraudulently authenticates the user.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Ah, I see.  How likely is that?  If someone is going to go to all that trouble, can't they just crack the software instead?

Comment: fake host more easy then crack. I don't want to prevent crack (it's impossible of course). I want to prevent connecting to fake server.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this might be through SSL/HTTPS.

Your license server would have a HTTPS endpoint that presents a SSL certificate. Your program would use a CA (certificate authority) to verify that the certificate returned from the server is authentic. This would prevent a user from providing a fake server via the HOSTS file.